# How can I prove that if $a > 1$ then for all $c ∈ \mathbb R$ there exists $n ∈\mathbb N$ such that $a^n > c$ using the binomial theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I was given a hint to let $a = 1 + b$ with $b > 0$ so I tried doing the binomial expansion on $(1 + b)^n$ to get $1^n + nb + \ldots + b^n$ but now I'm lost. Is this the right direction to go or am I completely off base? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $c\leq 0$, the statement is trivial. Can you show that for any $c>0$, there is an $n$ such that $n b>c$? Hint: Archimedean property.

Comment: YOu are so very close!  Notice that $b> 0$ so  $a^n=1^n + nb + ..... + b^n > 1+ nb$.  Can you always choose an $n$ so that $1 + nb > c$?  (Note: since $b > 0$ then $1+nb > c \iff n \ge \frac {c-1}b$.   Can you always choose such an $n$.  (Actually you *can't* take that for granted.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the binomial theorem.
Bernoulli's inequality is enough.

This is
if $x > 0$ and $n$ is a positive integer
then
$(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$.
This is easy to prove
by induction.

Then, as suggested,
let $a=1+b$
where $b > 0$.
Then
$a^n = (1+b)^n
\ge 1+nb
\gt nb
$
so it is enough if
$nb > c$
so that
$n \ge \dfrac{c}{b}$
then
$a^n > nc > c
$.

Nothing remotely original here.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Now it suffices to prove that given any $c > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nb > c$. Equivalently, that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > x := \frac{c}{b}$. The proof of this for when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is easy since if $x = \frac{p}{q}$ with $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$, then $x \leq p < p + 1$. If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the proof will depend on your precise definition of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple it's astonishingly deceptive.

You noted that $(1+b)^n = 1 + nb + ..... + b^n$.  But if $b > 0$ then $1 + bn + .... + b^n > 1+nb$.

So you just have to show that there exists an $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $1+bn > c$.

And as $b > 0$ then $1+bn > c \iff n > \frac{c-1}b$.  (It seems like there must be a catch but... it's all there.)

Now there *is* one catch.  You have to know that the natural numbers *are* unbounded.  Depending on your text that may be considered so obvious it is unquestioned;  or it is given as an axiom (which it *isn't* actually); or it is a corollary of the Archimedian property (which itself may either by given as an axiom [which it isn't really] or need to be proven).

Comment: Your re-ordering of the inequality for $n$ is not correct. Also, what is the purpose of keeping $1$? You can take $nb$ as a lower bound.

Comment: @Gary "Your re-ordering of the inequality for n is not correct. " It's not? It's the binomial theorem as the OP did it and it seems fine to me.  "Also, what is the purpose of keeping 1"There isn't any.  It just didn't occur to me to drop it.  I figure I'd keep the strings looking as similar and possible without adding more work.  ... Of course we can to $1 +nb > nb > c \iff b > \frac cn$.  Or if we wanted to be perverse $1+nb > nb-32 \iff n > \frac {c+32}n$.  So any $n > \frac {c-1}b$ or $n>\frac cb$ or $n> \frac {c+32}b$ will do just fine.

Comment: "Your re-ordering of the inequality for n is not correct. "  You fixed it after my comment. For the rest, I just think $>nb$ is the simplest and most elegant way of doing it.

Comment: I didn't change the "order of the the inequality".  But I had noticed I had left out the \frac tag.  So I fixed *that*.  "I just think >nb is the simplest and most elegant way of doing it"  And *I* think $1 + nb > c$ is the most *direct* way of doing it.  Wanna arm-wrestle for it?  ('taint like calculating $1+bn > c$ is going to waste *that* many brain cells).  And I guess the "astonishing deceptive" of "Why is $1+b + nb +....+b^n> c$" is easier to see "well $1+nb+..+b^n>c\implies1+b>c$" "... oh, yeah..." than $1+nb + ... +b^n> c\implies nb> c$" "...uh, wha..."